# Restart systemd service when GPU memory limit is reached

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I'm using the following systemd service on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The service is saved in `/lib/systemd/system/myService.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=myService
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/Data

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/project/main
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StandardOutput=append:/usr/local/bin/project/stdout.log
StandardError=append:/usr/local/bin/project/stderr.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My service is using the GPU. I would like to restart the service automatically if a certain amount of GPU memory usage (vram) is reached. I could use `MemoryHigh` and `MemoryMax` but I think this is for CPU memory only.

Is it possible to automatically restart a service when GPU memory is over a limit for a certain amount of time (e.g. 1min)? Peaks should not be detected but only when memory is too high for a longer amount of time.

Do you see any other improvements of the service? I would like that the service is always running, i.e. always restarting at boot and when it crashes. I think this I already achieved with the service file.